# mySQL: Given 2 column data, find 3rd column and then AVG() 3rd column based on 2nd column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

I've 3 columns, `staffName`, `dateOfIncident`, `incidentNo`. I'm looking for `'total incidents'` which will be the total number of incidents from a certain staff for a particular year, which I get from `dateOfIncident`. Now I must find the average of the number of 'total incidents', finally providing the headings:

```
staffName | avgIncidents
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT l.staffName, l.dateOfIncident, COUNT(l.incidentNo) AS avgIncidents
FROM incidentsR l
```

Which displays:

```
staffName | dateOfIncident | avgIncidents
....      | .....          | ....
```

Though this obviously supplies 3 columns output, and so far I'm only able to count the total amount of incidents, which I then need to use to calculate the `avg`.

What I need help with is how to take information from the first 2 columns of name and date to find the `'total incidents'` for that specific person for that year. And then for each `staffName` calculate the average of the number of `'total incidents'` for the years we have data on the staff.

Comment: You can use GROUP BY function

Comment: What's your desired output? And please add sample data..

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be:

```
SELECT l.staffName, year(l.dateOfIncident) as year,
       COUNT(*) as incidentsPerYear
FROM incidentsR l  
GROUP BY l.staffName, year(l.dateOfIncident);
```

To get the average per year for the staff, you *could* use a subquery.  Or do the calculation directly:

```
SELECT l.staffName,,
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT year(l.dateOfIncident))as avgIncidentsPerYear
FROM incidentsR l  
GROUP BY l.staffName;
```